# Display a thanks page in Drupal quiz module

Tags: drupal

I have the Quiz module installed in my drupal website. My client want to see a thanks page rather than a Quiz Result page, once the Quiz is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really used Quiz module soecifically, but I surmise can pass it a form state redirect using  hook_form_alter. Something like:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'form_id')
  {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULE_form_id_submit_handler';
  }
}
```

Then catch that with a custom submit handler:

```
function MODULE_form_id_submit_handler($form, &$form_state)
{
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/thanks/page';
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have somehow managed to fix the issue :)